# Calendar Functions

Tags: web-part, calendar

I am interested in creating a calendar view from a SharePoint list that contains asset IDs and dates, linked to entries in an Assets table.  My original intention was to create a custom web part to solve this problem.  Unfortunately, neither I nor anyone in the IT department seem to know who I could talk to regarding the server, so it's looking unlikely that I can actually run any significant code, and even if I could, I don't have the DLL that the MS docs mention in the context of setting up a development environment.  Does anyone know of any way that I could do this with ONLY built-in features?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the site columns `Start Date` and `End Date` to any list. Make sure they store time **and** date. Populate the columns with data. Then create a new view and select the `Calendar View` format. In the section for `Time Interval` select the respective columns for start and end date and in `Calendar Columns` select a column for the title for the different views of day, week and month. Save the view and enjoy.

You can also use other custom Date/Time columns, but why re-invent the wheel when the site columns already exist.